# SQL Finding Group where attendance less than average

Tags: sql, oracle

How can i get the number of attendees below average? This is my Oracle query

```
SELECT e.event_id EventID,c.concert_name ConcertName, c.concert_date, 
AVG(e.attendance) Attendance

FROM event e INNER JOIN concert c ON c.concert_id = e.concert_id 
WHERE  Attendance - AVG(e.Attendance)
GROUP BY c.concert_id ASC;
```

Comment: This is working but one of the rows shows attendance that is higher than the average. what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `AVG(..) OVER ()` analytic function (and without a correlated sub-query):

```
SELECT eventId,
       ConcertName,
       Concert_Date
FROM   (
  SELECT e.event_id EventID,
         c.concert_name ConcertName,
         c.concert_date,
         e.attendance,
         AVG(e.attendance) OVER () AS avg_Attendance
  FROM   event e
         INNER JOIN concert c
         ON c.concert_id = e.concert_id
)
WHERE  attendance < avg_attendance;
```

Comment: AVG FROM dual(e.attendance) OVER () AS avg_Attendance
             *
ERROR at line 9:
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis . * just is just before e.attendance

Comment: @user3346221 Thanks. Fixed, there was a missing comma before that line.

Comment: Its working but when i try to select additional fields in the select statement but i get an error. Am modifying the first part as follows  for comparison    SELECT eventId,
       ConcertName,
       Concert_Date, Attendance, AVG(Attendance)
Error: SELECT eventId,
       *
ERROR at line 1: ORA-00937: not a single-group group function Error near eventid

Comment: @user3346221 Use the `avg_attendance` which is already calculated in the inner query rather than trying to re-caulculate it with the aggregate function `AVG` in the outer query.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this way:

```
SELECT e.event_id EventID,c.concert_name ConcertName, c.concert_date, 
AVG(e.attendance) Attendance
FROM event e INNER JOIN concert c ON c.concert_id = e.concert_id 
WHERE  e.attendance < (select AVG(ev.attendance) from event ev)
GROUP BY c.concert_id ASC;
```